# Django query model - GROUP BY, MIN, MAX

Tags: django, django-models, sqlite

I'm having trouble transferring my query to django.
In sqlite3 it looked like this:

```
SELECT A, MIN(B), MAX(B) from table GROUP BY A
```

This would output unique values from A with a range of values from B
Any hints on how to approach this? Is it even possible in django?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `values()` for the `GROUP BY`, and `annotate()` for the `MIN` and `MAX`:

```
from django.db.models import Min, Max

MyModel.objects.values('A').annotate(min_b=Min('B'), max_b=Max('B'))
```

You'll get a list of dictionaries, containing the keys `A`, `min_b` and `max_b`.