# How do I convert this complex SQL into a Django model query?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm writing a Python/Django application to do some stock analysis.

I have two very simple models that look like this:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=5, null=False, editable=False, unique=True)

class StockHistory(models.Model):
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock, related_name='StockHistory_stock', editable=False)
    trading_date = models.DateField(db_index=True, null=False, editable=False)
    close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, db_index=True, decimal_places=5, null=False, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('stock', 'trading_date')
```

This is the dummy data I have populated them with:

```
import datetime
a = Stock.objects.create(symbol='A')
b = Stock.objects.create(symbol='B')
c = Stock.objects.create(symbol='C')
d = Stock.objects.create(symbol='D')

StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,1,1), close=200, stock=a)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,1,2), close=150, stock=a)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,1,3), close=120, stock=a)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,4,28), close=105, stock=a)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,5,3), close=105, stock=a)

StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2017,5,2), close=400, stock=b)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2017,11,11), close=200, stock=b)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2017,11,12), close=300, stock=b)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2017,11,13), close=400, stock=b)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2017,11,14), close=500, stock=b)

StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,4,28), close=105, stock=c)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,4,29), close=106, stock=c)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,4,30), close=107, stock=c)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,5,1), close=108, stock=c)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,5,2), close=109, stock=c)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,5,3), close=110, stock=c)
StockHistory.objects.create(trading_date=datetime.date(2018,5,4), close=90, stock=c)
```

I want to find all the stocks that made a yearly low within the past week.

But to make this question simpler, just assume that I want to find all the stocks whose lowest point since `'2017-05-04'` occurred on or after `'2018-04-30'`. Below is the SQL I wrote to find it. It works.

But I need help figuring out what Django Query to write to get the same results as this SQL. How can I do it?

```
mysql> select
    ->     s.symbol,
    ->     sh.trading_date,
    ->     low_table.low
    -> from
    ->     (
    ->         select
    ->             stock_id,
    ->             min(close) as low
    ->         from
    ->             stocks_stockhistory
    ->         where
    ->             trading_date >= '2017-05-04'
    ->         group by
    ->             stock_id
    ->     ) as low_table,
    ->     stocks_stockhistory as sh,
    ->     stocks_stock as s
    -> where
    ->     sh.stock_id = low_table.stock_id
    ->     and sh.stock_id = s.id
    ->     and sh.close = low_table.low
    ->     and sh.trading_date >= '2018-04-30'
    -> order by
    ->     s.symbol asc;
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| symbol | trading_date | low       |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| A      | 2018-05-03   | 105.00000 |
| C      | 2018-05-04   |  90.00000 |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Although your query is fine, note that we stopped using comma style JOINs circa 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, shouldn't that ampersand be a comma?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid and shouldn't `models` be `objects`?

Comment: Why the double post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50237534/how-do-i-convert-this-sql-into-a-django-query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:** I managed to reform the solution using Django subqueries.

We can translate the query to Django ORM using Django's [`aggregates with SubQuery expressions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression):

1. **Create a subquery to retrieve the lowest `close` for every `symbol`**:

   ```
   from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Min     

   lows = StockHistory.objects.filter(
       stock=OuterRef('stock'), 
       trading_date__gte='2017-05-04'
   ).values('stock__symbol')
   .annotate(low=Min('close'))
   .filter(trading_date__gte='2018-04-30')
   ```

   - ***Breakdown:***

     - `filter` the queryset to get only the stocks with `trading_date >= '2017-05-04'`.
     - "GROUP BY" `stock__symbol` (examples of group by in Djnago: [`GROUP BY ... MIN/MAX`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561631/django-query-model-group-by-min-max), [`GROUP BY ... COUNT/SUM`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547674/how-to-execute-a-group-by-count-or-sum-in-django-orm)).
     - `annotate` the lowest (`low`) price to every element.
     - `filter` the queryset again to get only the objects with a `low` field occurring on `trading_date >= '2018-04-30'`.
   - ***Intermediate Result:***

     Although we cannot get a result at this stage, the subquery will look like this:

     ```
     [
         {'stock__symbol': 'A', 'low': Decimal('105.00000')},            
         {'stock__symbol': 'C', 'low': Decimal('90.00000')}
     ]
     ```

     We are missing the `trading_date`.
2. **Utilize the subquery to retrieve the specific `StockHistory` objects:**

   ```
   StockHistory.objects.filter(
       stock__symbol=Subquery(lows.values('stock__symbol')),
       close=Subquery(lows.values('low')),
       trading_date__gte='2018-04-30'
   ).values('stock__symbol', 'trading_date', 'close')
   .order_by('stock__symbol')
   ```

   - **Breakdown:**

     - `lows.values('stock__symbol')` and lows.values('low') retrieve the respective values from the subquery.
     - `filter` the queryset against the `lows` subquery values. Also `filter` against the specified date in order to eliminate low `close` prices occurring before that date.
     - Get the specified `values`.
     - Order the result by `stock__symbol` (by default `ascending`).
   - **Result:**

     ```
     [
         {
             'close': Decimal('105.00000'), 
             'trading_date': datetime.date(2018, 5, 3), 
             'stock__symbol': 'A'
         }, 
         {
             'close': Decimal('90.00000'), 
             'trading_date': datetime.date(2018, 5, 4), 
             'stock__symbol': 'C'
         }
     ]
     ```

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I got the error `NameError: name 'OuterRef' is not defined`

Comment: @SaqibAli Did you forget to import it:  `from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Min`? If that is not the case, what version of Django and Python are you using?

Comment: Oops! Yes. Sorry. After doing the import, I now get this error: `ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`: https://gist.github.com/saqib-zmi/907398cc695660dbbf9c47e6929ec3db

Comment: @SaqibAli I believe that you tried to `print` or otherwise see the result of the `lows` subquery. `OuterRef` is not accessible outside of a `Subquery` call. You need to do step 1 AND 2 as shown in order to get the desired result.

Comment: Yes @JohnMoutafis, you were right about that. Now the Django you provided gives the same result as my SQL. I have a follow-up question. But I will accept your answer in the meantime and post that separately.

Comment: @SaqibAli Good to know!

Comment: Here is my follow-up question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286057/how-can-i-convert-this-sql-statement-to-django-queryset

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of Django (1.11, 2.0):

```
from django.db.models import Min
low_stocks_qs = StockHistory.objects.filter(trading_date__gt='2017-05-04').annotate(low=Min('close')).filter(trading_date__gte='2018-04-30').order_by('stock__symbol')
```

You can iterate through the queryset to get individual values of low and stock.symbol, maybe something like this:

```
low_stocks_dict = {}
for inst in low_stocks_qs:
    low_stocks_dict[inst.stock.Symbol] = inst.low
```

Comment: I see that you annotate a new attribute called `low` here. But you never use it. Right?

Comment: @SaqibAli I edited my answer. This is why I introduced `low`.

Comment: I would prefer the DB to do as much of the work as possible instead of my python code.

Comment: @SaqibAli then you may prefer using [raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/), but be careful of SQL injection.