# In Django, for a OneToOne relationship between two objects of the same class, can an object be prevented from referring to itself at the db level?

Tags: python, sql, django, database-design, django-models

I have the following in my app:

```
class University(models.Model):
    ...
    sister_university = models.OneToOneField('self', 
                        related_name = 
                        'university_sister_university', 
                        blank=True, null=True, 
                        on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

As it is, under the Django Admin site, I’m able to select University A as the sister_university of University A (itself). Is it possible to enforce some sort of a rule at the database level so a university object can never be its own sister_university?

Alternatively, is there a better way of accomplishing what I’m trying to do?

Comment: @BearBrown They’re two different questions. Same example code but the previous question asks whether *uniqueness* can be assured and the second question (this question) asks if I can prevent an object from referring to itself. So please don’t close this. Thanks!

Comment: you just added info about admin but unique for sister is present in two question

Comment: @BearBrown Maybe, I’m missing something. Can you please point me to where this question says “unique for sister”? I’d be happy to correct it.

Comment: @BearBrown The main point of this question is preventing an object from referring to itself, which is not an issue raised in the previous question.

Comment: to exclude the conflict situation in next time,  look on example in the top of the question: [statement-to-django-queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286057/how-can-i-convert-this-sql-statement-to-django-queryset)

Comment: @BearBrown That’s helpful. I’ll be sure to do that next time. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the model level, you can override the `clean()` method of your model to implement that check every time a `University` instance is saved.

```
def clean(self):

    if self.sister_university.id == self.id:
        raise ValidationError('A university object can never be its own sister_university.')
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `check` constraint, something like:

```
alter table university
add constraint chk_non_self_ref check (id <> sister_university_id);
```

I'm not aware of a way to define this in Django models (but I'm guessing you can add it to a migration).